# Can't reindex Catalog URL

Tags: magento-1, reindex

I have an shop that cannot reindex.

I've tried to re-index programmatically, with this code:

```
//Following 3 lines will load the magento admin environment.
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('admin');
umask(0);

// to reindex the processes we require their ids
// for default magento there are 9 processes to reindex, numbered 1 to 9. 
$ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

// Sometimes there are processes from our custom modules that also require reindexing
// We need to add those ids to our existing array of ids
// To know the id of process, just hover on each process in your
// admin panel-> System-> Index Management
// You will get a url : admin/process/some_id/......
// this id corresponds to the process

$ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 390, 391, 478);
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    //load each process through its id
    try {
        $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($id);
        $process->reindexAll();
        echo "Indexing for Process ID # " . $id . " Done<br />";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

But I still get an error. Here is the error:

> An error occurred while saving the URL rewriteSQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`pukindustri`.`#sql-c67_7a9d2c9`,
>   CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_MAGE_MAGE_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_MAGE_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `mage_catalog_product_entity`
>   (`entity_id`) ON)Indexing for Process ID # 5 Done

Can someone help me to get the reindex to function again?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594063/magento-and-error-1452-integrity-constraint-violation-on-reindex-catalog

Comment: No luck. According to that artikle, if it return nothing there is no problem. But i still have the problem.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110817/reindex-error-magento-1-9-x-x

Comment: No luck with this one :(